# Call Perl script from Python

Tags: python

I've got a Perl script that I want to invoke from a Python script.  I've been looking all over, and haven't been successful.  I'm basically trying to call the Perl script sending 1 variable to it, but don't need the output of the Perl script, as it is a self contained program.

What I've come up with so far is:

```
var = "/some/file/path/"
pipe = subprocess.Popen(["./uireplace.pl", var], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
pipe.stdin.write(var)
pipe.stdin.close()
```

Only just started Python programming, so I'm sure the above is total nonsense.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you just want to open a pipe to a perl interpreter, you're on the right track. The only thing I think you're missing is that the perl script itself is not an executable. So you need to do this:

```
var = "/some/file/path/"
pipe = subprocess.Popen(["perl", "./uireplace.pl", var], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
pipe.stdin.write(var)
pipe.stdin.close()
```

Comment: the `./` part in the script call is useless and i can't see the use of the two last line, and this two last line can lead to bugs !!

Comment: If you are providing absolute path and perl executable then ./ is not in use.

Answer (score 17):

Just do:

```
var = "/some/file/path/"
pipe = subprocess.Popen(["perl", "uireplace.pl", var])
```

Comment: Just a note: since the OP says he doesn't want to get the output, `Popen` is not required. Using `subprocess.call` or `subprocess.check_call` is better.

Comment: @sukhbir: i think when the OP say that he don't need the output, i can also "assume" that he also don't want to wait until the perl script finish which what `subprocess.call` or `subprocess.check_call` does :)

Comment: so using this if the perl script were to run in terminal and i want to rerun it everytime the perl script crashed, and would have to use an if pipe = error message than rerun the perl code or something like that?

Comment: @pyCthon: Sorry but i didn't understand very well your question, what i understood is that you're running a Perl script using the code above and you want to make sure that if the Perl script crash, it should be re-spawn, right ?

Comment: @pyCthon; Well i am not sure about the context where you want to do this, but one way that i can think about is to execute ``Popen.poll`` (http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll) at a fix interval to check if the process is alive or not, so you can re-spawn it when it's crash i.e. ``Popen.pool() != 0``, you can run this mechanism in a Thread for example, other ways will involve using something like http://upstart.ubuntu.com/ or http://supervisord.org/ .

Answer (score 3):

You could try the [subprocess.call()](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#convenience-functions) method.  It won't return output from the command you're invoking, but rather the return code to indicate if the execution was successful.

```
var = "/some/file/path"
retcode = subprocess.call(["./uireplace.pl", var])
if retcode == 0:
    print("Passed!")
else:
    print("Failed!")
```

Make sure you're Perl script is executable.  Otherwise, you can include the Perl interpreter in your command (something like this):

```
subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/perl", "./uireplace.pl", var])
```

Answer (score 2):

Would you like to pass `var` as a parameter, on stdin or both?  To pass it as a parameter, use

```
subprocess.call(["./uireplace.pl", var])
```

To pipe it to stdin, use

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen("./uireplace.pl", stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
pipe.communicate(var)
```

Both code snippets require `uireplace.pl` to be executable.  If it is not, you can use

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen(["perl", "./uireplace.pl"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
pipe.communicate(var)
```

Answer (score 0):

I Hope [this](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyPerl) can help you. Do not know how to do that otherwise.

Comment: thank you for the reference... it was created and supported by activestate.. they seems dropped it?