# How to capture input prompt from command that is run thru Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a Perl script that prompts for "Enter" input from user. I need to run this perl script thru Python. How can I show that prompt message to user or catch the prompt and send inputs values to Perl thru Python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrapping an interactive CLI in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962141/wrapping-an-interactive-cli-in-python)

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you want to use input native python function.

```
x = input('Please input your input') # this will prompt the user to type
```

Now you can use the input for your perl script. This only answers part of your question , as this is just capturing the prompt and sending it to perl.

You can also execute perl script in python:
You can find more answers here : [Call Perl script from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682088/call-perl-script-from-python)

Comment: Please [do not post an answer that consists essentially of a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Include the important points in your answer; leave the link for extra information or as a reference.

Comment: that I know. How do I know in Python if Perl is asking for input?